# Application.Match Error 2015

Tags: vba, excel

I have spreadsheet with over 30k rows of data, each with 38 data points. In order to determine if there are any duplicated rows, I concatenated 14 of the fields for each row, and trimmed the data. This created a key for each row comprising of 349 characters.

Edit: The duplication of the key occurs when all 14 fields are the exact same. From a visual review, I have identified about 200 rows (out of 2000) where the data in all 14 fields is the exact same.

I then ran a search using application.match to determine whether that key had already been created. When there is no duplication, the application.match function works fine. However, when there is a duplication, it returns

> Error 2015

I understand that this is when the function is returning #VALUE. When I check using the immediate window, the values are duplicates, and when I type "=Xi=Yj" in the spreadsheet, it says that are the same (i.e. TRUE)

As I need to know the correct row value for the next part of the project, what I am wondering is if there is any way to identify the duplicate values, and get a correct row value?

The code I have is as follows (still only a PoC):

```
While Cells(a, 1) <> vbNullString

    If Cells(a, 36).Interior.Color = 5296274 Then

    ElseIf Cells(a, 36) <> vbNullString Then

    Else
        Cells(a, 39) = Trim(Cells(a, 3) & Cells(a, 4) & Cells(a, 5) & Cells(a, 6) & Cells(a, 7) & Cells(a, 8) & Cells(a, 9) & Cells(a, 10) & _
        Cells(a, 11) & Cells(a, 12) & Cells(a, 13) & Cells(a, 14) & Cells(a, 15) & Cells(a, 16) & _
        Cells(a, 17) & Cells(a, 18) & Cells(a, 19))

        Cells(a, 44) = Len(Cells(a, 39))

        m = vbNullString

        m = Application.Match(Cells(a, 39), Range(Cells(2, 39), Cells(a - 1, 39)), 0)

        If m = vbNullString Then
            Cells(a, 39).Select
            Selection.Style = "Good"

        Else
'            Range(Cells(a - 1, 39), Cells(a, 39)).Select
'            Selection.Style = "Bad"

        End If
    End If
    a = a + 1

Wend
```

Comment: Are you collecting all locations of duplicated keys or only the occurrences after the first? And please fully reference ranges. Or place them within a With statement and then prefix with "."

Comment: A tip:  `Cells(a, 39) = Join(Application.Index(Cells(r, 3).Resize(, 17).Value, 0, 0), ";")`

Comment: @QHarr - Not sure I follow the second part of the question. For the first, I need to know the location of each one, including changing the first one if subsequent ones change it to being non-unique

Comment: @JohnyL - that looks interesting. Could you expand on what you are doing in it?

Comment: The `Join` concatenates array vales with delimiter (`;` in this case). However, we have a problem: `Join` expects array to be 1-dimensional, while array returned by `Range.Value` is always 2-dimensional. That's why Application.Index kicks in - it just returns one dimension.

Comment: @JohnyL - Ok. Thank you. However, when I replaced the concatenation with that, it doesn't change the application.match error

Comment: But it was a tip :) As for the question, what is duplicate for your app? Does it mean than if *all* fields in two rows are identical, then they are duplicates? For instance, in database a primary key is usually one or two keys which must be unique through all the table. Is it your case?

Comment: I'll edit to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, I figured the reason for the error.

The keys that were being created were 349 characters long. A lot of Excel's functionality has a max character limit of 256 (0 - 255).

Based on that, I cut the keys down using the trim function.

The code now looks like:

```
While Cells(a, 1) <> vbNullString

    If Cells(a, 36).Interior.Color = 5296274 Then

    ElseIf Cells(a, 36) <> vbNullString Then

    Else
'        Cells(a, 39) = Join(Application.Index(Cells(a, 3).Resize(, 17).Value, 0, 0), ";")
        Cells(a, 39) = Trim(Cells(a, 3)) & Trim(Cells(a, 4)) & Trim(Cells(a, 5)) & Trim(Cells(a, 6)) & Trim(Cells(a, 7)) & Trim(Cells(a, 8)) & Trim(Cells(a, 9)) & Trim(Cells(a, 10)) & _
        Trim(Cells(a, 11)) & Trim(Cells(a, 12)) & Trim(Cells(a, 13)) & Trim(Cells(a, 14))

'       & Trim(Cells(a, 15)) & Trim(Cells(a, 16)) & Trim(Cells(a, 17)) & Trim(Cells(a, 18)) & Trim(Cells(a, 19))) removed

        Cells(a, 44) = Len(Cells(a, 39))

        m = vbNullString

        m = Application.Match(Cells(a, 39), Range(Cells(1, 39), Cells(a - 1, 39)), 0)

        If m = vbNullString Then
            Cells(a, 39).Select
            Selection.Style = "Good"
'            Cells(a, 41).Select
'            Selection.ClearContents

        Else
            Cells(a, 39).Select
            Selection.Style = "Bad"
            Cells(a, 40) = m

            Cells(m, 39).Select
            Selection.Style = "Bad"
            Cells(m, 40) = a

        End If
    End If
    a = a + 1

Wend
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to embed the error in a condition, with two options. Like this:

```
If IsError(Application.Match(Cells(a, 39), Range(Cells(2, 39), Cells(a - 1, 39)), 0)) Then
     'm = something
Else    
     m = Application.Match(Cells(a, 39), Range(Cells(2, 39), Cells(a - 1, 39)), 0)
End If
```

Comment: Therein lies the problem. It only gives an error where the I need "m" to give a value. Where it finds nothing, it is returning m = vbnullstring, which is correct

Comment: @Clauric - then just write something else on the `If IsError` condition.